# Não estou a conseguir usar aspas num valor da função"Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token"

Tags: javascript, html

A função não deixa passar o "Marco" como valor por causa da utilização de aspas, alguma ideia de como posso resolver (sem retirar as aspas)? Código :

```
<<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <script>
        function muda(x){
            document.getElementById('campo').innerHTML = x;
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>

    <button onclick="muda('\"Marco\"')">Clicar</button>
    <div id="campo" style="width: 100px; height: 100px; background-color: green;"> Oá</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: O lance do `&quot;` resolveu o seu problema?

Comment: sim resolveu o problema

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você pode usar `&quot;` para imprimir as aspas duplas:

```js
function muda(x){
    document.getElementById('campo').innerHTML = x;
}
```

```html
<button onclick="muda('&quot;Marco&quot;')">Clicar</button>
<div id="campo" style="width: 100px; height: 100px; background-color: green;"> Oá</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use aspas simples para delimitar o atributo e aspas duplas na função, sendo que a que vai na string deve estar escapada:

```js
function muda(x){
   document.getElementById('campo').innerHTML = x;
}
```

```html
<button onclick='muda("\"Marco\"")'>Clicar</button>
<div id="campo" style="width: 100px; height: 100px; background-color: green;"> Oá</div>
```

> Se você quisesse enviar aspas simples na string, seria o contrário:

```
onclick="muda('\'Marco\'')"
```